# Error with create CSV in server with PHP

Tags: php, csv, server

I have code to create a CSV file with SQL query data and then I send it by email.

```
function create_csv_string($data) {
    mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
    echo mysql_error();
    mysql_select_db("xxxxx");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT NOMBRE, TELEFONO, HORARIO, EMAIL FROM _LEADS WHERE ENVIADO = 0");
    echo mysql_error();
    if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+')) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        echo "entra";
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array('Nombre', 'Telefono', 'Horario', 'Email'));
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) fputcsv($fp, $line);
    rewind($fp);
    return stream_get_contents($fp);
}
```

My problem is that I executing this in local and it works, but I upload it to a server and it doesn't work. I think that the problem is in `!$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+'))` but I am not sure.

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*` functions, as they are deprecated and removed. Try using `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: The problem seems to be in MySQL Server and the file permissions. Can you set the permissions as `777` **just for a moment** and check? You can use something like `chmod -R 777 /var/www` or something.

Comment: Have you tried by giving filename with path in fopen function?

Comment: Ok, I change mysql_* to mysqli_* later. How I can change permissions?? Like this? if (!$fp = fopen('php://temp', '777')) { sorry I am rookie in php.. @PraveenKumar

Comment: But my file is not exist.. in my localhost works.. @sAcH

Comment: @oihi08 I said you how to do it. The server is a Linux or Windows? Sorry for the late response, I was on a call.

Comment: Create an empty file and try, some time the server doesn't have the permission to create file, but can write to file. @oihi08...

Comment: I put this: if (!$fp = fopen('/php/temp.csv', 'w+')) { but I dont know if it is ok.. I create this file in this folder. @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
<?php
    function create_csv_string() {
        echo "entssssra?";
        $connection = mysqli_connect("**","**","**","**") or die("Cannot Connect to MySQL Server");
        $data = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT NOMBRE, TELEFONO, HORARIO, EMAIL FROM _LEADS WHERE ENVIADO = 0");
        // Build the CSV:
        $csv = "'Nombre', 'Telefono', 'Horario', 'Email'" . PHP_EOL;
        while (false != ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)))
            $csv .= array_values($line);
        echo $csv;
        return file_put_contents('temp.csv', $csv);
    }
```

And you don't need the `$data` as a parameter.